# Java applet in <embed> html tag displays code rather than run

Tags: java, html, applet

Whenever I run the web page with my Java applet embedded, the entire code is displayed on the page  rather than run. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Streaming Applet</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Streaming Applet</h2>
    <embed src="RTPAudioPlayer.java" width="400" height = "300">
        <param name="rtp" value="rtp://192.168.1.7:10000/audio" />

</body>
</html>
```

In the tutorial I borrowed some of the code from the author used `RTPAudioPlayer` without the `.java`, but when I try that I get a 404 error.

Comment: You're supposed to embed the class not the java source. Fix that first.

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).